# Warning from iTunesConnect "Build does not contain the correct beta entitlement"

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I have uploaded an iOS app to iTunes connect. Currently the status of the app is "**In Review**". But iTunes shows me a warning like this,

"**Build does not contain the correct beta entitlement**"

I took a research and found that I need to re-generate my provision profile and by uploading a new binary with that profile will fix the issue.

Is it possible to reject the currently uploaded binary with "In Review" status ?
Or should I wait for the app rejection from the apple ?

Anyone please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can reject I think. Go to binary detail on iTunes Connect page and there should be option called "Reject this binary".

Comment: iTunes UI has been changed and I didn't find that option anywhere. :(

Comment: See there should be one section called Build on App info page. And in that version number is as hyper link. Tap on it and you should redirected to page where you can reject binary.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your existing provisioning profile from your machine & download latest provisioning profile from developer account , compile code and upload again.
With iOS 8 apple has introduced test flight & for that they have added beta related tags in provisioning profile